# how to keep lan on VM and remove it from host

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to keep lan working on VM (virtual-machine) and remove it from the host , whenever I disable lan on the host it disabled in VM , I am using wifi on the host to connect it remotely because connecting remotely using lan is restricted in our company , so I'm connecting using wifi to the host and connecting from host to VM to use the lan through VM , but if wifi router going down for a while the host will connect to active lan and it will not go to wifi when it restored , so I want to disable lan on host and keep it in VM ,(I'm using virtualbox as VM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. One is dependent on the other.

Your VM is using your network drivers and protocols in order to work. whether it's by a hard line or Wifi.

Comment: Thanks for answering , so is there any way to give wifi priority on the lan , whenever wifi signal come back the PC can leave lan and reconnect to wifi

Comment: I found way to make wireless connection priority from Network Connections >> Advanced Settings , but it's doesn't reconnect my PC to wifi again when signal restored